# Background for proof of LOOCV formula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, cross-validation

I'm supposed to prove the LOOCV formula for linear regression $$\text{CV} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\bigg(\frac{y_i - \hat{y}_i}{1-h_i}\bigg)^2$$, where $h_i$ is the diagonal element of the hat matrix. I found [this page](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/loocv-linear-models), which computes $y_i-\hat{y}_{[i]}$., where $\hat{y}_{[1]}$ is the predicted value when the model is estimated when the ith observation is deleted. What I don' understand is how this helps us in proving the formula? What is the link between $y_i-\hat{y}_{[i]}$ and $y_i-\hat{y}_{i}$?

Comment: They call it $\hat{y}_{[i]}$, not $\hat{y}_{(-i)}$, sorry for the confusion. I think $\hat{y}_i$ is the ith predicted value.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the link between $y_i-\hat{y}_{[i]}$ and $y_i-\hat{y}_{i}$?

The first, $y_i-\hat{y}_{[i]}$, is in the definition of the LOOCV error

$$\text{CV} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\left(y_i - \hat{y}_{[i]}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\bigg(\frac{y_i - \hat{y}_i}{1-h_i}\bigg)^2$$

The LOOCV formula re-expresses it in terms of the residuals for regular OLS: ${y_i - \hat{y}_i}$. The $h_i$ expresses how much the $i$-th data-point has an influence on the OLS estimated value of $\hat{y}_i$. The more this influence, larger the magnitude of $h_i$, the more the error will decrease/increase when we leave out the $i$-the point.